# Quadratic algorithm for 4-SUM

Tags: algorithm, sum

The 4-SUM is as follows:

> Given an array of N distinct integers find 4 integers a, b, c, d such that a+b+c+d = 0.

I could come up with a cubic algorithm using quadratic algorithm for 3-SUM problem. Can we do better than cubic for 4-SUM?

Comment: Yep. `O(n^2 log n)`. Also, here's the question and answer for the general case: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can. Go over all pairs of numbers and store their sum(and also store which numbers give that sum). After that for each sum check if its negation is found among the sums you have. Using a hash you can reach quadratic complexity, using std::map, you will reach `O(n^2*log(n))`.

EDIT: to make sure no number is used more than once it will better to store indices instead of the actual numbers for each sum. Also as a given sum may be formed by more than one pair, you will have to use a hash multimap. Having in mind the numbers are different for a sum `X = a1 + a2` the sum `-X` may be formed at most once using `a1` and once using `a2` so for  a given sum `X` you will have to iterate over at most 3 pairs giving `-X` as sum. This is still constant.

Comment: How do you make sure you don't choose the same element twice?

Comment: @amit `"also store which numbers give that sum"`. If you found a number chosen twice, just ignore that sum. I imagine there's a simple improvement, but not in the big-O complexity.

Comment: But this sum might be generated in a different form as well, You should store a list or something per sum, and look for the first element in that list that does not contain one of the two elements. Can you prove it is O(1)? (looking in this list)

Comment: @amit in fact I was considering using a hash multimap for that very reason.

Comment: Please extend your answer itself to contain how exactly is it making sure you do not use the same element twice.

Comment: @alex23 The lookup is O(log n), which results in O(n^2.log n). Storing all solutions of additions of 4 integers is O(n^4).

Comment: @amit please take another look

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: What if we are not allowed to use more than constant amount of extra space? Can we still do it in O(n^2*log(n)).

Comment: @Bruce I don't think this is possible, or at least I am not aware of such solution

Comment: Don't know if and how can you handle the input of `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` with the target sum of `0`.

Comment: The input consists on *unique integers* according to the statement

Answer (score 8):

There is also a O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm for this problem using O(N<sup>2</sup>) extra memory.

1. Generate all the pairwise sums in O(N<sup>2</sup>) and store the pair (a<sub>i</sub>, a<sub>j</sub>) in a hash table and use the absolute value of their sum as the key of the hash table (a<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>j</sub> are two distinct numbers of the input array)
2. Iterate over the table and find a key which has both negative and positive sum with four distinctive elements and return is as the answer

There is an alternative if you prefer not using hash table. Since your numbers are integers, you can sort the list of all the sum in a linear time of the elements in the sum list using something like a **Radix sort** (there are O(N<sup>2</sup>) elements in the sum list).

Comment: Codes speak loader.

Comment: For step 2 you are iterating over a table of size O(N^2) (all possible pairs). You want to find a key with 2 elements and another with 2 elements. i.e. you need to check all possible key-pairs in the table of size O(N^2). This will require looping over all O(N^2) keys twice to find the pair. This makes the algorithm O(N^2 * N^2) = O(N^4) which is no better than brute force (except you're also using O(N^2) space) or am I missing something?

Comment: I am an idiot who had a momentary lapse in judgement. You obviously just check your first key and then check for the existence of the negation of that key in the hash in O(1). This means you iterate once over the dictionary with O(N^2) keys meaning the final algorithm is still O(N^2) just like you say.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my code for a 4-sum problem, which will give you Quadratic Time complexity. You can run this program with any given sum number. In your case you want the sum to be zero, so passing 0 in function parameters. The idea is we can precompute the sum of a + b and store into a map first if it does not exist in the map, and then we can do `c + d` and checking if target `-(c + d)` is in the map.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FourSumPractice {
    public List<List<Integer>> quadTuple(int[] arr, int len, int sum){
    Map<Integer, Set<List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Set<List<Integer>> res = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            int requiredSum = sum - (arr[i] + arr[j]);
            if(map.containsKey(requiredSum)){
                for (List<Integer> l : map.get(requiredSum)) {
                    int x = l.get(0);
                    int y = l.get(1);

                    if((x != i && x != j) && (y != i && y != j)){
                        List<Integer> quard = Arrays.asList(arr[i], arr[j], arr[x], arr[y]);
                        Collections.sort(quard);
                        res.add(quard);
                    }
                }
            }
            map.putIfAbsent(arr[i] + arr[j], new HashSet<>());
            map.get(arr[i] + arr[j]).add(Arrays.asList(i,j));
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(res);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] A = { -10, 30, -15, -5, -5, -25, 0, 10, 51 };
    int sum = 0;
    FourSumPractice obj = new FourSumPractice();
    List<List<Integer>> l = obj.quadTuple(A, A.length, sum);
    for(List<Integer> sub:l){
        for(int i : sub){
            System.out.print(" "+ i);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
       }
    }
}
```