# O(n² log(n)) algorithm to find all numbers in array such that x² + y² = z² + u²

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of positive integers, find a `O(n² log(n))` algorithm to find all distinct numbers combinations for numbers `x, y, z, u` such that it satisfies

> x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = z<sup>2</sup> + u<sup>2</sup>

Basically, I see how you get *x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = z<sup>2</sup>* using `O(n² log(n))` time

> sort then iterate and use a binary search

but to do the same with an additional `u²`

Comment: What have you tried? It's always best to add this information to a question.

Comment: i tried a similar approach that we iterate all through possible x and y's (assuming sorted) so it's n^2 - then we need a similar z^2 and a binary search but that is O(n^3 log(n))

I have another idea - add all possible x^2+y^2 and z^2+u^2 combinations possible - then binary search the correct values based on the two arrays of possible sums - does that work? requires much space.

Comment: Could you add that information to the question? You might want to check out [these tips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking good questions. Thanks!

Comment: @AdiInbar Algorithm questions are on topic for [so] and much less appropriate for [math.se].

Comment: Square everything and use this solution - [Quadratic algorithm for 4-SUM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14732277) (possible duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quadratic algorithm for 4-SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732277/quadratic-algorithm-for-4-sum)

Answer (score 2):

**There is no O(n<sup>2</sup>logn) solution** for the simple reason that there could be O(n<sup>4</sup>) possible solutions, and if you need to *find* them, the output size itself is O(n<sup>4</sup>).

Have a look on `[1,1,1,1,....,1]` every combination of (a,b),(c,d) will satisfy the demands. There is `Choose(n,4)` which is in O(n<sup>4</sup>) possible solutions.

However, if we denote the output size as `m`, it can be done in O(n<sup>2</sup>logn+m):

```
map<number,list<pair>> m = new map
for each i in 1...n:
   for each j in i+1...n:
     map.add(arr[i]^2+arr[j]^2,(i,j))
for each entry number that is key in the map:
   list = map.get(number)
   print all pairs (i,j),(x,y) in the list such that i!=x,j!=u,i!=y,j!=x
```

Where `map` is some tree-based map.

If you don't want 'repeated answers' (that actually stands for repeated elements in the list) like in the [1,1,1...,1] example, by changing the `map<number,list<pair>>` to `map<number,set<pair>>`, and inserting the values instead of the indices - you will get it.

Comment: Nice solution, if you use a hashMap, with `hash(Pair) = sum(Pair)`, the solution should be on the same hash-code

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer The OP asked for O(n^2logn), I assumed he's looking for worst case behavior, which cannot be guaranteed using hash maps, that's why I specified it's a tree-based.

Answer (score 1):

**Input:** `List L = { L1, L2, .. Ln }`

**Algorithm**

1. `D = { Di | Di = Li^2 }` square all numbers
2. `T = { Ti | Ti = Di+Dj, i!=j }` distinct 2-Sums
3. `S = { Si | Si = (Ti,Tj), i!=j, Ti=Tj }` find equivlant 2-Sums

**Analysis**

```
T(Step(1)) ~ n

T(Step(2)) ~ (n^2 - n)

T(Step(3)) ~ (n^2 - n)

T = n + (n^2 - n) + (n^2 - n)

T = n^2 + n^2 + n - n - n

T = 2n^2 - n ~ O(n^2)
```

**Code**

*Solution.Java*

```java
class Solution
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int [] L = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 3, 3 };

        int [] D = new int [L.length];

        for (int i=0; i<L.length; i++)
            D[i] = (L[i]^2);

        int nbSums = D.length^2 - D.length;
        int z = 0;

        int [] T = new int [nbSums];

        for (int i=0; i<D.length; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<D.length; j++)
                if (i != j)
                    T[z++] = D[i] + D[j];

        ArrayList<Pair> S = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        for (int i=0; i<T.length; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<T.length; j++)
                if (i != j && T[i] == T[j])
                    S.add(new Pair(T[i], T[j]));
    }
}
```

*Pair.java*

```java
class Pair
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Pair (int a, int b)
    {
        this.first = a;
        this.second = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two problems with the solution. (1) It is not O(n^2), there is no O(n^2) solution if you need to *find* all elements. (2) for a list [1,1,3] this solution will return (1,3),(1,3) as a solution (it reuses elements)