# Leetcode: Four Sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum

Problem: Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c, and d in S such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target.

Note:
Elements in a quadruplet (a,b,c,d) must be in non-descending order. (ie, a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d)
The solution set must not contain duplicate quadruplets.

For example, given array S = {1 0 -1 0 -2 2}, and target = 0.

```
A solution set is:
(-1,  0, 0, 1)
(-2, -1, 1, 2)
(-2,  0, 0, 2)
```

I know there's an O(n^3) solution to this problem, but I was wondering if there's a faster algorithm. I googled a lot and found that many people gave an O(n^2logn) solution, which fails to correctly deal with cases when there are duplicates of pair sums in S (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569504/find-four-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number-x) 
and [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-four-elements-that-sum-to-a-given-value-set-2/)). I hope someone can give me a correct version of an O(n^2logn) algorithm if it really exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quadratic algorithm for 4-SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732277/quadratic-algorithm-for-4-sum)

Answer (score 2):

The brute-force algorithm takes time O(n^4): Use four nested loops to form all combinations of four items from the input, and keep any that sum to the target.

A simple improvement takes time O(n^3): Use three nested loops to form all combinations of three items from the input, and keep any that sum to the negative of the target.

The best algorithm I know is a *meet-in-the-middle* algorithm that operates in time O(n^2): Use two nested loops to form all combinations of two items from the input, storing the pairs and totals in some kind of dictionary (hash table, balanced tree) indexed by total. Then use two more nested loops to again form all combinations of two items from the input, and keep the two items from the nested loops, plus the two items from the dictionary, for any pair of items that sums to the negative of a total in the dictionary.

I have code at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/08/14/4sum/).

Comment: Would you mind telling me which of the solutions provided in the link is yours? Thanks.

Comment: The one in the text of the exercise, on page 2, is mine. The ones in the comments were written by the author of the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your code. However it seems that the code is written in a programming language that I don't know. I was wondering if you could rewrite it in C++/Java/Python or pseudocode so that I could understand it more easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, for O(n^2lgn) algorithm, the problem of duplicates can be solved when creating the `aux[]` array. (I'm using the name in the second link you provided). The basic idea is first sort the elements in the input, and then while processing the array, skip the duplicates.

```
vector<int> createAuxArray(vector<int> input) {
  int len = input.size();
  vector<int> aux;

  sort(input.begin(), input.end());

  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (i != 0 && input[i] == input[i - 1]) continue; // skip when encountered a duplicate

    for (int j = i + 1; j < len; ++j) {
      if (j != i + 1 && input[j] == input[j - 1]) continue; // same idea

      aux.push_back(createAuxElement(input[i], input[j]); 
    }
  }
  return aux;
}
```

Complexity for this module is O(nlgn) + O(n^2) = O(n^2), which doesn't affect the overall performance. Once we have created `aux` array, we can plug it into the code mentioned in the post and the results will be correct.

Note that a BST or hashtable can be used to replace the sorting, but in general it doesn't decrease the complexity since you have to insert/query (O(lgN)) inside 2-nested loop.

Comment: I think what you are doing here is to skip duplicates in the array, but the pair sums you got still may have duplicates. Sorry that I didn't make this clear and I've updated my post. The problem with the solution provided in the second link is that: suppose the input array is: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] and target = 14. You have multiple combinations with sums equaling to 7. When iterating through the array aux, that solution would skip some of the combinations when it found ( 7 + 7 == 14). And in order to avoid this, all the pairs with sum of 7 should be compared to each other.

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood your question. You are right, my solution still cannot handle the problem. But I'm afraid the other answer is not O(n^2) (sorry that I can only comment here because of low reputation...). Like I said in my answer, generally its complexity is still O(n^2lgn) because it requires (at least, depending on the implementation) O(lgn) to query in the hashtable/BST. And since it is using the sum of pairs as an index, there could be many collisions. So the in worst case the complexity for that algorithm is at least O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of the geeksforgeeks solution which handles duplicates of pair sums as well. I noticed that some of the pairs were missing because the hash table was overwriting the old pairs when it found new pair that satisfies the sum. Thus, the fix is to avoid overwriting by storing them in a vector of pairs. Hope this helps!

```
vector<vector<int> > fourSum(vector<int> &a, int t) {
    unordered_map<int, vector<pair<int,int> > > twoSum;
    set<vector<int> > ans;
    int n = a.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) twoSum[a[i] + a[j]].push_back(make_pair(i, j));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (twoSum.find(t - a[i] - a[j]) != twoSum.end()) {
                for (auto comp : twoSum[t - a[i] - a[j]]) {
                    if (comp.first != i and comp.first != j and comp.second != i and comp.second != j) {
                        vector<int> row = {a[i], a[j], a[comp.first], a[comp.second]};
                        sort(row.begin(), row.end());
                        ans.insert(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int> > ret(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    return ret;    
}
```