# Can we do 4-sum algorithm in O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, hash, time-complexity, complexity-theory

this is related to the following question:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem

Without loss of generality, let's only consider even `k`, or just `k = 4`.

My question is, after summing all pairs of numbers, is it necessary to sort the list of sums? I understand we could use two pointers from left and right to sandwich the two pairs in `O(n^2)` time, but the sorting requires `O(n^2 log(n))` time.

If we use a hashmap to store the sums as key and their corresponding index pairs as value, then all operations can run in `O(n^2)` time.

Am I missing something in that post or is it true for even `k`, `k`-sum can run in `O(n^{k/2})` time?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to count number of 4 sums or print the quadruple also?

Comment: @Kaidul I think the complexity stays the same for both applications. But let's say we want to print all such 4-tuples.

Comment: No, if you want to list all the quadruples, the complexity will be much higher

Comment: @Kaidul In the hashmap we could store list of all pairs of indices which sum to the number. Then we just need to enumerate quadruples from two such pairs to print them all. This shouldn't increase the complexity.

Comment: @Kaa1el imagine all 4 quadruples satisfy the condition, then there are O(n^4) such quadruples

Comment: @Kaidul, maybe I am wrong, but let's go back to say we just need to print one such quadruple or just the decision problem which checks if the list has such quadruple. Even this situation I can't say for sure why we need to sort the sums.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quadratic algorithm for 4-SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732277/quadratic-algorithm-for-4-sum)

Answer (score 2):

There are some subtleties, but you're right that average performance for the decision problem can be made that good.  However it requires two hashmaps, not one.

The first hashmap is from the left, and it will store as value `(i1, j1)` where `i1 < j1` and `j1` is the minimum index for which that sum can be achieved.

The second hashmap is from the right, and it will store as value `(i2, j2)` where `i2 < j2` and `i2` is the maximum index for which that sum can be achieved.

Now run through the keys of the first hashmap, looking for the opposite in the other.  If both are in there and `j1 < i2` then you have your quadruple.

However note a subtlety.  With sorting the expected and worst case time is `O(n^2 log(n))`.  With a hash your expected time is `O(n^2)` but it is theoretically possible to get `O(n^4)` if your hashing algorithm breaks down.  (Hashing algorithms don't generally break in practice, which is why we consider them `O(1)`.)